# Web API cannot resolve symbol Http in System.Web.Http, what is missing?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a webforms project.
I use nuget to install web API by running `Install-Package WebApi.All`
I create a class

```
public class CartController : System.Web.Http.ApiController
```

but it cannot resolve symbol Http in System.Web.Http, what dependency am I missing?

Comment: Have you installed ASP.NET MVC/Web API for VS 2010?

Comment: @Aliostad, it's not an MVC app, however I did try nuget `Install-Package AspNetMvc` but I still get the same result.

Comment: @mgnoonan, I'm targeting .Net 4.0

Comment: I ran `Install-Package WebApi.All`. It gives me `Unable to find package 'WebApi.All'`

Comment: I can't think of a good reason why, but maybe you need to install MVC 4 in order to get all the necessary bits.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The name of the package for the ASP.NET Web API isn't "WebApi.All". The package for the ASP.NET Web API (Beta) is "AspNetWebApi". Try running the following instead:

```
Install-Package AspNetWebApi
```

Comment: `update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi –reinstall` may help if there is version inconsistency

Answer (score 0):

Try using it with exact keyword from the [package manager console](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console). This is include the dependencies `WebApi.Enhancements`, `WebApi.OData`.

> Install-Package WebApi.All -Version 0.6.0

For more information checkout NuGet [WebApi.All 0.6.0](http://nuget.org/packages/WebApi.All)

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use "NuGet Package Manager".

You can simply use "NuGet Package Manager" by right clicking on Project from Solution explorer, and search "Web API" term. Install it from there.

[image: NuGet Package Manager]